# Any way to see files pending/uploading/downloading and specify priorities in SkyDrive?

Tags: onedrive

Is there any way to find out which files SkyDrive is uploading (and which ones are pending to upload) in SkyDrive? Also, any way to specify file priorities?

Answer (score 1):

SkyDrive app does not have action log and you can't specify the priorities.
To see the syncing status, open the SkyDrive folder (right click the SkyDrive icon in the system tray and then click Open your SkyDrive folder) and check for files that have a blue circular arrows. This icon indicates that they are still syncing. The green check marks are for files that are already synched.